# DocuSign API- How do I let other signer or reviewer make changes to a completed document?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a power form that is created by an originator and signed and fill by them and then sent to two additional consecutive signers/viewers to approve or deny. How can I give either one of those last 2 signers the ability to send back to the originator to make changes to fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, what you're proposing requires a complicated API program:

You could have a checkbox tab "Return to 1st signer" along with a reason text tab.

Then create a webhook that will check the value of the checkbox tab. If it is checked, then add a new set of signers (duplicates of the first set). The second time around, the 1st signer can change his request.

So in this proposal, the sender/first signer is being added as an additional signer. The envelope is not being routed "back" to the first signer, the first signer is being added (again) as an additional signer.

You will also need the envelope to not complete after the approvers disapprove the original request. That can be done with a fake confirmed copy or signer recipient that is later removed.

Or, if the "do over" checkbox is checked, you could initiate a new ("second try") envelope. That would probably be an easier API program. In this case, the first envelope would be deleted or voided.

Comment: thanks @larry-k I found this solution on community also. I was looking for API which returns inline frame url which loads editable document page. I looked in API documentation, found that completed envelope can be purge only.

Comment: @lazydeveloper -- correct, once an envelope (transaction) is complete, that's it. So the trick is to modify the envelope's signer's list before the envelope reaches the complete stage. That can be done via a fake signer which you later delete.

Comment: we are using iframe mode as well. I don't think above solution possible.is it?

Comment: iFrame (embedded signing) is a small detail compared with the rest of the app. All do-able but requires software development.

Comment: I have achieved my requirement, what I have done is : cloning (deep copy) completed envelope from completed one having drafted status and sending signer again with proper message

Comment: Thank you for the update (and check). And thank you for using DocuSign. @lazydeveloper

Comment: can you look into this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726510/add-signer-on-template-based-docusign-envelope   @larry-k