# Add signer on template based docusign envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have created a template and added two role signer1 & signer2.I am creating envelopes & adding signers on fly using this template.Its working fine.In some case,admin user don't know 2nd signer and adding only first signer and envelope is created with single signer.Once envelope is created,Now I want to add 2nd signer on envelope.I am using C# docusign client, I tried

```
  {                 
     var templateInfo = await envelopesApi.ListTemplatesAsync(await AccountAsync(), envelopeId, new EnvelopesApi.ListTemplatesOptions { include = "applied" }); //fetching template id
                foreach (var template in templateInfo.Templates)
                {
                    var templateRecipients = await templatesApi.ListRecipientsAsync(await AccountAsync(), template.TemplateId, new ListRecipientsOptions { includeTabs = "true" }); //fetching tabs assigned to roles in templatea
                Var signer=  templateRecipients.Signers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.RoleName.ToLower() == signer.SigningRole.ToLower())
                    Recipients.Signers = signers.Aggregate(new List<Signer>(), (newSigners, signer) =>
                    {
                        string recipeintId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        Tabs tabs = templateSigner.Tabs;
                        Tabs newTabs = new Tabs();
                        var newSigner = new Signer
                        {
                            Email = signer.Email,
                            Name = signer.FullName,
                            RoleName = signer.SigningRole,
                            //ClientUserId = signer.Email,
                            RecipientId = recipeintId, //Int or Guid expected
                            Tabs =BuildRecipientTabs(recipeintId,signer?.Tabs) ; //copying tabs
                        };
                        newSigners.Add(newSigner);
                        return newSigners;
                    });


    var something = await envelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsAsync( AccountId, envelopeId, recipients);
}
//
         private Tabs BuildRecipientTabs(string recipientId, Tabs tabs)
        {
            Tabs newTab = new Tabs();
            if (tabs.ApproveTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.ApproveTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.CheckboxTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.CheckboxTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.DateTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.DateTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.DateSignedTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.DateSignedTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.DeclineTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.DeclineTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.EmailAddressTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.EmailAddressTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.EmailTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.EmailTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.EnvelopeIdTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.EnvelopeIdTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.FullNameTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.FullNameTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w!=null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId;}});             
            }
            if (tabs.FirstNameTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.FirstNameTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.FormulaTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.FormulaTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.InitialHereTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.InitialHereTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }           
            if (tabs.LastNameTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.LastNameTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.ListTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.ListTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.NotarizeTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.NotarizeTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.NoteTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.NoteTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.NumberTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.NumberTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.PolyLineOverlayTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.PolyLineOverlayTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }           
            if (tabs.RadioGroupTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.RadioGroupTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.SignerAttachmentTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.SignerAttachmentTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.SignHereTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.SignHereTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; w.TabId = null; } });
            }
            if (tabs.SmartSectionTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.SmartSectionTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.SsnTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.SsnTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.TitleTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.TitleTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.TextTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.TextTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId;  w.TabId=null; } });

            }
            if (tabs.TabGroups != null)
            {
                tabs.TabGroups.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }          
            if (tabs.ViewTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.ViewTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            if (tabs.ZipTabs != null)
            {
                tabs.ZipTabs.ForEach(w => { if (w != null) { w.RecipientId = recipientId; } });
            }
            return tabs;
        }
```

its adding recipients but not associated with template role.Can anyone suggest how recipients can be assigned template role?

Answer (score 1):

I just found solution for this requirement.Tabs are not created or updated using ***UpdateRecipientsAsync*** or ***CreateRecipientsAsync***

It worked using ***CreateTabAsync***..

```
 //build recipients
                recipients.Signers = signers.Aggregate(new List<Signer>(), (newSigners, signer) =>
                {
                    string recipeintId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var newSigner = new Signer
                    {
                        Email = signer.Email,
                        Name = signer.FullName,
                        RoleName = signer.SigningRole,
                        ClientUserId = signer.Email,
                        RecipientId = recipeintId //Int or Guid expected                      
                    };
                    newSigners.Add(newSigner);
                    return newSigners;
                });
                var addedRecipient = await envelopesApi.CreateRecipientAsync(await AccountAsync(), envelopeId, recipients); //adding recipients
                var templateInfo = await envelopesApi.ListTemplatesAsync(await AccountAsync(), envelopeId, new EnvelopesApi.ListTemplatesOptions { include = "applied" });

                //envelope is created using one template only
                    var templateRecipients = await templatesApi.ListRecipientsAsync(await AccountAsync(), templateInfo.Templates.FirstOrDefault().TemplateId, new ListRecipientsOptions { includeTabs = "true" });
                    foreach (var signer in recipients.Signers)
                    {
                        Signer templateSigner = templateRecipients.Signers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.RoleName.ToLower() == signer.RoleName.ToLower());
                        Tabs tabs =BuildRecipientTabs(signer.RecipientId, templateSigner.Tabs);
                        var t=  await envelopesApi.CreateTabsAsync(await AccountAsync(), envelopeId, signer.RecipientId, tabs);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the recipients object include recipients and if you make sure that the role matches to what's in the template - it should work.
Please share your entire code for further assistance.

Comment: new signer is added but signer tab which I define in template is not assigned !!!

Comment: is the tab for this role? and is the roleName specified when you add the new signer?

Comment: yes..for role R ,a tab is defined which contains Sign Here fields.

Comment: you are copying your tabs over, but I'm not sure they include all the information inside the object. Can you please check they include the recipientId?

Comment: if there is something wrong then API call should return errors but its not responding success

Comment: well, you are not doing something wrong, you are just not doing what you plan to do. You are adding a new tag to a new recipient instead of updating the tags for the existing role.

Comment: its by design of docusign 
```UpdateRecipients``` method will update only recipient details.for tab,we need to use another method.I did it in my solution
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/236

Comment: glad you figured it out